# Is there a way to allocate directly to the heap without using the unstable box syntax?

Tags: rust

I'm in the process of getting a project of mine targeting WASM, and it appears that the stack size in the browser is relatively small and non-configurable. A consequence of this is that my application will overflow the stack while attempting to allocate 
a large struct on the heap, due to the intermediate stack allocation when calling `Box::new()`. The [unstable `box` syntax](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49733) fixed this, but it appears to be dead in the water.

I managed to get it running without `box`, albeit in a less-than-ideal fashion. I had to refactor my structs to hold reference to boxed data in order to allocate in smaller chunks.

Is there a way to allocate directly to the heap without `box`?